mamba claims package is already installed when it is not
When installing seaborn, mamba says it is already present. Yet trying to import it in my python interpreter (the mamba one) fails:
(base) ➜  materials git:(main) ✗ mamba install seaborn

Looking for: ['seaborn']

conda-forge/linux-64                                        Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.10.*


Transaction

  Prefix: /home/mathurin/mambaforge

  All requested packages already installed

(base) ➜  materials git:(main) ✗ python -m seaborn
/home/mathurin/mambaforge/bin/python: No module named seaborn

Yet it seems that everything happens in my mambaforge folder so it's the correct path and interpreter?

What is the output of mamba list?

I'm not exactly sure of the root cause, but the package had been installed twice, with pip and mamba. Running pip uninstall seaborn and mamba uninstall seaborn allowed for a clean reinstall afterwards.
